# Can pressure drag ever have a linear relationship?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, drag

I know from aerodynamics that pressure drag has a quadratic relationship for high Reynolds number of $10^4$ but what if the Reynolds number is between 1 and 10^3 say can pressure drag have a linear relationship with velocity of power of 1.5 for example.

Comment: The semantics of the term "pressure drag" appear to exclude viscous drag.  If you set the latter to zero, then dimensional analysis demands a quadratic relationship.  The 1.5-power relationship must apply to total (not pure pressure) drag.

Comment: @james2018  You want to ask if the coefficient $c_P$ depends on the Reynolds number?